# Employee Feedback Solution In SharePoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

We have a requirement to deliver an Employee Satisfaction & Feedback solution on SharePoint 2013.

We have in-house development resources but I would like to evaluate all options like 3rd Party tools & developing our own.

My question is what 3rd Party Solutions provide this type of functionality that we could purchase that may meet the requirement but also provide other functions like employee surveys etc.?

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for a developed solution, nor a 3rd party tool. Surveys are built in to SharePoint 2013 OOTB:

[image]

Comment: Does it provide ability to give actual, textual feedback? Haven't used it almost at all so far and just wondering about first hand experience working with it :)

Comment: Sure! You decide what type of feedback on every survey question: Yes/No, multiple choice, single choice, text box e t c. Try it out. You can set permissions in a way that users only see there response and that the number of responses is hidden.

Comment: That's excellent, definitely solution fitting OPs big picture, you can easily extend the Survey using the usual Best Practices approaches and  that will do nicely if I ever need to deliver such functionality in the future. Knowing SharePoint projects it means I'll get to do so almost immediately :) Cheers!

Comment: I know about surveys OOTB in SharePoint but they can be cumbersome to extract data from. I still need to complete due diligence so need other options.